# Passing a Picklist value from Aura component to my Apex Class

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am confident I am missing something small here, but need other eyes.

I am trying to pass a value to an Apex class. I cannot get it to pass. I have read many posts on here, but still cannot seem to get it to function.

Class:

```
public with sharing class Nearby_Agents_Map {
/*piclist selection for BD/RIA */
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Account> getPicklist(){
    List<Account> options = new List<Account>();
    //options.add('-none-');
    List<Account> account = [Select Id, Name From Account Where Name like '%- CORPORATE%'];
    for(Account a : account)
    {
        options.add(a);
    }
    system.debug(options);
    return options;
}
@AuraEnabled
public static list<contactLocationWrapper> getContactLocation(Id recordId, Decimal dist, Id ACT){
    system.debug(recordId);
    List<Contact> ConLoc = [SELECT Account.Account_Stage__c, MailingLatitude, MailingLongitude FROM Contact WHERE ID = :recordId];
    Decimal Lat = ConLoc[0].MailingLatitude;
    Decimal Lon = ConLoc[0].MailingLongitude;
    list<contactLocationWrapper> lstALW = new list<contactLocationWrapper>();
    /*Query accounts records with billing address information */  
    system.debug(ACT);
    If(ACT!=null){
        for(contact con : [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone, MailingLatitude, MailingLongitude, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingPostalCode, MailingCountry, Account.Account_Stage__c 
                       FROM Contact 
                       WHERE distance(MailingAddress, geolocation(:Lat, :Lon), 'mi') < :dist 
                       AND (Account.Account_Stage__c = 'Selling Agreement Won' 
                            OR Account.Account_Stage__c = 'Site Visit | Investment Committee'
                            OR Account.Account_Stage__c = 'Due Diligence')
                       AND MailingCountry != null
                       And MailingCity != null
```

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="Nearby_Agents_Map" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="Distance" type="Decimal" />
<aura:attribute name="BD_RIA_Account" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="mapMarkersData" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="markersTitle" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="listView" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="ACT" type="Account" default="{'sobjectType' : 'Account'}"/>
<aura:attribute name="ActList" type="Account[]" />
<aura:attribute name="zoomLevel" type="Integer" default="4" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}" />
<lightning:layout>    
    <lightning:layoutitem>
        <ui:button label="Search" press="{!c.myAction}" class="btn" />
    </lightning:layoutitem>
    <lightning:layoutitem>
        <ui:inputText class="field" aura:id="Radius" value="{!v.Distance}" /> (Search Radius in Miles)
        <select aura:id="PicklistId"> 
            <option value="" text="- None -"/>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.ActList}" var="act">
                <option value="{act.Id}" text="{!act.Name}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </select>
        (Choose BD/RIA)
    </lightning:layoutitem>
</lightning:layout>
<!-- init handler which will call 'doInit' fucntion on component load-->
<!-- <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>-->

<!-- render map component only when we have at least 1 record in list.(mapMarkersData) -->   
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.mapMarkersData.length > 0}" >
    <!-- the map component -->
    <!-- markersTitle="{! v.markersTitle }" showFooter="{ !v.showFooter }" -->
    <lightning:map mapMarkers="{! v.mapMarkersData }"
                   markersTitle="{! v.markersTitle }"
                   listview="{! v.listView }" 
                   zoomLevel="{! v.zoomLevel }"
                   />
</aura:if>
```

Controller:

```
({
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getPicklist");
    var account = component.find("PicklistId");
    var opt=[];
    action.setCallback (this, function(response){
       var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
        console.log('allValues___>>'+allValues);
        component.set("v.ActList", allValues);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    // call getLocation apex class method 
    console.log('Shits and Giggles - 2');
    var selected = Array.prototype.filter.call(
        component.find("PicklistId").getElement().ActList, 
        function(option) { 
            return act.selected; 
        }).map(function(option) {
            return act.value;
            }
    );
    console.log('Shits and Giggles - 2');
    var action = component.get("c.getContactLocation");
    action.setParams({
        recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
        dist:component.get("v.Distance")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            // set mapMarkersData attribute values with 'accountLocationWrapper' data 
            component.set('v.mapMarkersData',response.getReturnValue());
            component.set('v.markersTitle', 'Agent Locations:');
            component.set('v.listView', 'hidden');
            component.set('v.zoomLevel', 11);
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // do something
        }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);       
}
```

})

Any help is appreciated. I did not list the entire Apex class only up until where I need it passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to use [lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleSelectChange). But In your case to get the selected value.

```
<select aura:id="PicklistId"> 
            <option value="" text="- None -"/>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.ActList}" var="act">
                <option value="{act.Id}" text="{!act.Name}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
 </select>
```

Use aura:id to get the selected value. and you miss the third parameter to pass in your apex method

```
myAction:function(cmp,help,evt){

 //Get the picklist value
 let selectedValue = cmp.find('PicklistId').get('v.value');

 let action = component.get("c.getContactLocation");
   action.setParams({
    recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
    dist:component.get("v.Distance"),
    ACT : selectedValue
   });
}
```

Comment: I altered my code as above and I am still receiving "undefined" in my console log. Unfortunately it is still not passing the selection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    component.find("PicklistId").getElement().ActList, 
    function(option) { 
        return act.selected; 
    }).map(function(option) {
        return act.value;
        }
);
```

In this chunk of code I don't think act is actually defined. Did you not mean to use option instead as that is the parameter name you are defining for your function?

And here, it seems like you're missing a parameter:

```
action.setParams({
    recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
    dist:component.get("v.Distance")
});
```

I think you want your third parameter to be your account Id from above so it should be:

```
action.setParams({
    recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
    dist:component.get("v.Distance"),
    ACT:selected
});
```

Comment: I altered my code to the below: 
        var selected = Array.prototype.filter.call(
     component.find("PicklistId").getElement().ActList, 
      function(ACT) { 
          return ACT.selectedValue; 
      }).map(function(ACT) {
          return ACT.value;
         }
  );
        var action = component.get("c.getContactLocation");
        console.log(selectedValue);
        action.setParams({
      recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
            dist:component.get("v.Distance"),
            ACT:selectedValue
  });
        console.log(selectedValue);
Unfortunately nothing